# $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] gives server IP rather than visitor IP

Tags: php

I'm trying to track IP addresses of visitors. When using `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, I get the server's IP address rather than the visitor's. I tried this on multiple machines at multiple locations and they all resulted in the exact same IP. Is there some PHP/server settings that could be affecting this?

Comment: Can you link us to the site to confirm?  Have you also checked the values (IF PRESENT) of `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. I'm going to go ahead and ask the Unix admins what the issue could be. It is not an issue on any of our other servers.

Comment: This can be a misconfiguration of the web server or some sort of proxy  on the way. The mystery might be solved if you find out who's IP it is :)

Comment: It happens to me too. I have a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 and VestaCP installed. If I use HTTP_X_REAL_IP then it's correct. Vesta is using NGINX so I guess that's the problem (reverse proxy)

Answer (score 22):

> When using $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], I get the server's IP address rather than the visitor's.

Then something is wrong, or odd, with your configuration.

- Are you using some sort of reverse proxy? In that case, @simshaun's suggestion may work.
- Do you have anything else out of the ordinary in your web server config?
- Can you show the PHP code you are using?
- Can you show what the address looks like. Is it a local one, or a Internet address?

Answer (score 21):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the IP address from which the request was sent to the web server. This is typically the visitor's address, but in your case, it sounds like there is some kind of proxy sitting right before the web server that intercepts the requests, hence to the web server it appears as though the requests are originating from there.

Comment: I have developed a LIKE SYSTEM where I get real IP of users. Now, I'm facing one issue. 
I'm connected to home wi-fi. When I click on LIKE button on laptop it works. When I check same in different browser, it works.

But, When I open site on my mobile then two IP register in my DB. One is router IP and other one is mobile's IP. But, mobile IP changes in every few seconds. SO, my system thinks that it's different person and count vote from same person as different person.

Comment: I think it is generally agreed that using IP address for any sort of ID of users is a very bad idea as there are so many ways that the IP address will be wrong, change, duplicated.  Find another mechanism.  @KalpeshSingh

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will find a better solution soon.

Answer (score 9):

Look no more for IP addresses not being set in the expected header. Just do the following to inspect the whole server variables and figure out which one is suitable for your case:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Comment: i found what i was looking for ths way it was: HTTP_X_REAL_IP : json_encode($_SERVER) <- if you need to log it

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
  $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
  $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
  $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
}
```

Comment: explanation pleasee..... for more better understanding

Answer (score 2):

Replacing:

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

With:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"];
```

Worked for me.

Comment: *Only* do this if you are sure *your* reverse proxy sets this header. Don't accept arbitrary HTTP headers from clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudflare then this is always the Cloudflare IP address from the node which is serving you.

In this case you get the real IP address from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']` entry as described in the the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

if your site is behind cloudflare, you can use another header provided by cloudflare itself:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
```

or if you are using Laravel

```
$request->server('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP');
```

read more about it here:

[How to get real client IP behind Cloudflare in Laravel / PHP](https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-get-real-client-ip-behind-cloudflare-in-laravel-php)

Answer (score 0):

#php 7.x short condition syntax.

```
<?php
$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo "The user IP Address is - ". $ip;
?>
```

from https://www.delftstack.com/howto/php/php-get-user-ip/

Comment: Watch out for PHP 7.4, this is deprecated.

Comment: @tibelchior what specifically is deprecated ?

Comment: @mfort the left-associative ternary operator
Read more about it here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity

Comment: @tibelchior But if I add parentheses as the second example in [https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity#proposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity#proposal) for example
`$ip = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`
It will work?

Comment: @mfort Yes, but I would place the parenthesis in the last block, as you already one check in the left block. The rest is just a fallback.

$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`

Comment: As mentioned by deceze under another answer do not use this if your website is not behind a known proxy to you (e.g. cloudflare) headers with `HTTP_` prefix can be set from client (even with a simple javascript), and if you know the proxy, you definitely will not need to check other headers either.

Answer (score 0):

Enable remoteIP module in your Apache server

`a2enmod remoteip`

Restart Apache: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart