# How to trace visits from automated bots to your website?

Tags: php, bots, spam

I own a website that is used to show interstitial advertisements to the visitors and I share the revenue with the user who shared the link.

My problem is spammers. There are spammers who put the link in automated bots who visit my website from different IPs. So I get automated visits in huge numbers that actually do not add any value to my site.

Is there a possibility of identifying such ip addresses or visits using one or the other header in HTTP?

Can it be done in PHP?

Thanks,
Himanshu Joshi

Answer (score 0):

you mean to log the IP addresses? using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']...

[$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] gives server IP rather than visitor IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip)

You can also atleast log them by storing the IP Address and the Time they visited your website, and calculate it by using some simple codes...atleast to limit a certain IP Address such as 1 Visit is equal to 1 credit per day only...

Comment: Hi Daison, I am already logging the ips and date-time. But how do I classify it to be a bot rather than authentic visit?

Comment: The only ways you can do is, to allow CAPTCHA every single visit, but that is the most worst idea I can gave you....You can't find if the visitor is a bot or not, you may also lessen the bot by finding out PUBLIC IP Addresses like PROXIES and limit them to count every credit...maybe it takes a million of rows to log those PROXY IPs

Answer (score 0):

Unless these bots identify themselves in the headers, it is unlikely that you will be able to know if a single visit is from a bot or a human.

The spammers have been doing this for a while and the larger sites spend a lot of resources working to resolve this issue (it is not an easy issue to solve).

As a starting point you could:
- make people login to post anything, and use a captcha system to slow the spammers down (this annoys web users though)
- look at the time stamps of the visits - if a single IP address reads all the pages in a second and then posts multiple spam links then it probably is a bot.  Your server host may have tools in place to do this.