# REMOTE_ADDR not working

Tags: php

I have a wierd problem. Whatever i do, the IP is the server's IP, not the client / the visitor. What to do?

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARTDED_FOR'] != '') {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip_address;
}
```

Comment: what webserver do you use?

Comment: is the control going to this part of the code:
else {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?

Comment: Your IP must be on HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR? Have you dumped $_SERVER and see what else do you have? Some load balancers will use different keys.

Comment: duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip)

Comment: I have dumped yes, showing wrong ip-address still. It's the server's client IP i think, not mine.  My server is from Germany, dedicated.

Comment: Instead of wasting your time, udexter, go something else. I have already tried that solution.Or else i wouldn't ask.

Comment: There is a typo in `HTTP_X_FORWARTDED_FOR` that would also cause the condition to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to switch to another server software (depending on what you're using now)

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. **There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.** That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

`REMOTE_ADDR` is in the [CGI/1.1 specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) though so it's odd that whatever server you're using wouldn't be returning it.

Comment: Well, there is no other solution? I have dedicated server.

Comment: @JesperMadsen What operating system and server software are you running? That's what matters, not the physical box.

Comment: @JesperMadsen Obviously php. I'm assuming apache is your web server software? If that's the case it's more likely a routing problem.

Comment: [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635

Comment: @JesperMadsen you should add that to your question, that's useful info. I doubt my answer is the problem then....

Comment: Ok, so how can i fix this routing problem??

Comment: @JesperMadsen the support for whatever hosting provider you're using would be a good place to start.

Comment: How can i configure my server to let it work? It's dedicated, no help from webhost, because its self-managed. :(

Answer (score 1):

If your server is on the same network as your server, behind a router with NAT, then you might see your private IP.

If you are behind a reverse proxy `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` will always be the IP of the proxy server.

Comment: I have nothing to do with the server, it's dedicated and i am on another computer in Denmark, my server is from Germany.

Comment: @JesperMadsen: not your machine. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is not configured properly (once I've had this issue on buying alias domains at my webhost provider).
However if you're unable to fix this problem, I **HIGLY** recommend you to check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` is valid IP address and then just assing it to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for simply usage, because It is easy to fake `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` and to throw there your own values (I had this problem).

Comment: How can i configure my server to let it work? It's dedicated, no help from webhost, because its self-managed.

Comment: I am sorry I was not fixing it, because it was problem of my webhost provider, not my own server :/ Btw. I was not reading whole discussions here, but what do you mean by its dedicated? You've just installed everything as usually and the problem is just in this? Maybe its some setup of network, no idea at all, but why dont you just check if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is valid ip and if yes, make $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; so you can use everywhere in your code REMOTE_ADDR as usually. For me it sounds fine, why dont u like it? :)