# parsing a url localhost vs online

Tags: php, url, localhost

I have this simple method which checks if a url is for part of my admin area.

```
protected function is_admin_url ( $url ) {
    $parts = parse_url( $url );
    if ( !empty($parts['path']) ) {
        $steps = explode('/', $parts['path']);
        if ( $steps[1] == $this->slug ) // $steps[0] will always be empty
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It should return `true` for any url in the form `http://example.com/slug/foo?bar=baz`
The problem I'm having is that while developing on my local machine (using WAMP) all urls are in the form `http://localhost/example.com/slug/foo?bar=baz`. This of course breaks the method since the domain is now part of the path.

Hard coding the array index is bound to lead to bugs. Is there any conditional statement I can add in to handle this?

I should also note, this is part of a plugin for WordPress. The site url is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is a dot in `$steps[1]` or just check if you are working in a local environment:

```
protected function is_admin_url ( $url ) {
    $parts = parse_url( $url );
    if ( !empty($parts['path']) ) {
        $steps = explode('/', $parts['path']);
        $slug = $steps[1];
        if (strpos($steps[1], '.')) $slug = $steps[2];
        if ( $slug == $this->slug )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or

```
protected function is_admin_url ( $url ) {
    $parts = parse_url( $url );
    if ( !empty($parts['path']) ) {
        $steps = explode('/', $parts['path']);
        $slug = $steps[1];
        if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') $slug = $steps[2];
        if ( $slug == $this->slug )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The dot method works in theory but my slug is a settable parameter. I believe dots are allowed in folder names, making this approach problematic. I shouldn't trust the value of REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: Because it can return anything. How about "::1" or the servers online IP. Sure I can configure to use my machines setting, but coding on another machine may give a wrong result.

Comment: I don't think you would run into much trouble using it, anyway, if you want something else try with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === "localhost"`. Also, about REMOTE_ADDR: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773981/653378

Comment: I've accepted your answer for the dot method. I can simply impose a restriction on the setting of the slug. It sure beats messing around with REMOTE_ADDR

Answer (score 0):

Just check the part between the most recent /s

```
protected function is_admin_url ( $url ) {
    $pFile = strrpos($url, '/');
    $pFolder = strrpos($url, '/', $pFile-1);
    if (($pFile === false) or ($pFolder === false)) {
        return false;
    }
    $folder = substr($url, $pFolder+1, $pFile-$pFolder-1);
    return ($folder == $this->slug);
}
```

BurninLeo

Comment: Doesn't work with urls like `http://localhost/example.com/slug/foo/?bar=baz` or multiple folders

Comment: I think that you task is not adequately defined. What should the method accept as "admin URL" and what not? Is a "slug" anywhere in the URL sufficient? Or should it rather check all possible admin folders to avoid false positives?

Comment: The slug will always be the first folder

Comment: No. Your localhost example just proved that it will not.

Comment: And that's why I wrote this question.

Comment: So ... define your task correctly, and the solution will follow :) If the folder can be on position 1 *or* 2 depending on the domain, this would be something you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Check with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='127.0.0.1' for detect if is development environment or put in global config a variable $local = true and use inside function is_admin_url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip REMOTE_ADDR cannot be trusted