# Is the web server variable $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] reliable?

Tags: php, superglobals

I have generally assumed that in a PHP script I can test `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  to establish the IP address from which the request originated.  However, I am starting to wonder if things are not a bit more complicated.  Here is the scenario

- I run a number of servers, call them **A**, **B** and **C** -  on which users have to be "registered"
- I run a separate registration server, call it **S**,  where the users' credentials etc are first verified prior to sending out a complete registration request to servers **A, B and C**

The request goes out as

```
file_get_contents('https://url?data=value')
```

On servers **A, B and C** I was quite naively testing `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to establish that the request was in fact coming from server **S**.  Much to my surprise the results turned out to be patchy and variable

1. The value in `REMOTE_ADDR` was the IP address of the human user interacting with the registration server, **S**
2. The value in `REMOTE_ADDR` was the IP address of the registration server, **S** - what I had expected to see **all the time**
3. The value in `REMOTE_ADDR` was another IP address from the pool of IP addresses on the virtual server where I host server **S**

I don't really need to perform this additional verification test so I can drop it out altogether. Nevertheless this result has taken me by surprise so I am curious to see if someone here can shed some light on what is going on.

I should mention that I am running PHP 5.5  on *Lighttpd* on servers **A, B and C** and PHP 5.3 on Apache 2 on server **S.**

Comment: Do you use PHP as a `module` or `fcgi/fpm`? Please check also the variables `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, as all of the three variables are differently populated when using different servers, (reverse)proxies and configuration.

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773969/is-it-safe-to-trust-serverremote-addr). What is your exact question? If it is "is REMOTE_ADDR unreliable" the answer is "yes, it is, if you expect it to contain always some specific computers address. It is reliable in the way it tells an ip of some computer that the connection is coming from".

Comment: the ip address `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the public IP address to directly respond to - it's not possible to fake it (unless the attacker doesn't care to receive the response). From what's in the question: there are flaws in how you're testing, as that's not how it works.

Comment: @eis That's a pretty misleading comment.

Comment: If you are doing server to server communication (Server S to Server A), it is impossible to have the human visitor's IP in `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: @eis because the remote addr is unambiguous. If it were unreliable a server would not be able to send a response to a client (browser). The first duplicate indicates some kind of misconfiguration, it's not the norm; the second clearly states [It is the source IP of the TCP connection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773981/761202). Basically if it was unreliable the web as a whole wouldn't work.

Comment: @AD7six REMOTE_ADDR can point to a firewall, a proxy, a VPN endpoint or something else. For this computer I'm using I can select whichever proxy I want, so it is not reliable in telling what computer I'm using. That has nothing to do with server ability to send out a response to a client.

Comment: @eis please read the question again - is any of that relevant? Is it possible for me to make a request to server A, server A to issue `file_get_contents('http://google.com');` and google to see my public IP (or that of my router, or that of my proxy, or that of my firewall etc.)?

Comment: @AD7six Sure it is. Server-to-server traffic can, and often do, use proxies too, especially in an enterprise context. They can also use gateway servers, for instance.

Comment: @eis you think that DroidOS has configured his server to use the client as a proxy for outbound requests? Are we reading different questions? If you have a proof of concept that calls `file_get_contents('http://example.com');` passing *the end-clients IP* I'd like to see it.

Comment: @AD7six I did not claim that DroidOS has configured proxies, and I did not mention it passing the end-user ip. However, I do think your statement "the remote addr is unambiguous. If it were unreliable a server would not be able to send a response to a client (browser)." is the misleading comment here.

Comment: I believe `REMOTE_ADDR` can also contain a list of IP numbers, or even `"unknown"`.

Answer (score 3):

`REMOTE_ADDR` is a variable that Apache (or any other web container) fills, it contains the IP address of the terminal at the other end of the communication.

Is it reliable? Yes.

Is it secure? Depends, if you use it thinking that it presents you with the IP address of the user making the call, you're wrong, any proxy standing in the way will corrupt the information.

In your case, the server emitting the HTTP call should provide its IP address, so scenario 2 should happen all the time. I don't know what went wrong at what moment but its weird.

To respond to Dany Caissy, don't rely on `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, it can easily be modified as it's an HTTP header, and not a TCP/IP property.

Comment: I'm just giving him the options, I didn't claim any of them were safe or not, it's his responsibility to account for security and it isn't part of this question.

Comment: I know your intention was for a good reason :), it's just worth to mention for people coming to read this for the first time, that doing  `$myCustomersIP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];` is wrong. But I totally agree with you :)

Comment: @Shotgun `getallheaders()['X-Forwarded-For']` ended up being the ideal solution to a head-scratcher. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

REMOTE_ADDR isn't the only way to get the IP Address, there are also :

```
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_X_FORWARDED
HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_FORWARDED
```

They are set in different ways and can mean different things, ultimately, it is very difficult to get the IP Address you want to have.

EDIT : The only one of them that is reliable and can't be modified by the user is REMOTE_ADDR, but it won't always do exactly what you want, so you'll HAVE to use the other ones, no matter how 'unsafe' everyone says they are.

Comment: By all the gods - no. Don't even think to rely on `X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Comment: @AlmaDo `X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be relied on in some cases. Specifically when you have a cache/load-balancer in front of your server and always clear any external `x-forwarded-for` headers. Only the user-provided values should never be trusted.

Comment: It can be _checked_ (at best - to get some information). But it should _never_ be _relied_

Comment: relying on `X_FORWADED_FOR` is a gaping security hole. See for example [this post](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html). `it is very difficult to get the IP Address you want to have.` - no it isn't =). The question is asking for the ip address of the machine initiating the request, not e.g. the public IP of the end-client.

Comment: There is nothing else to rely on. If you run your own front-end proxies for anything, you have to rely on x-forwarded-for. Or some other header that will have exactly the same function. The only thing you could do to improve the trust is to sign the field, but I don't know of any software capable of that out of the box.

Comment: @viraptor there is "read" and there is "rely". Don't attribute any meaning (except possibly unique-but-anonymous identity) to headers which are user-defined - see the post [I linked to earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388744/serverremote-addr-is-unreliable?noredirect=1#comment37721604_24388864) for an example.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the various comments. As I mention in my question I do not really need the additional IP address check.  The data I send out are heavily encrypted and contain a stringent timeout that will, as a last resort, ensure that servers A,B, C ignore the request. So I have just dropped any notion of IP testing. It is nevertheless useful to cast away my ignorance and not place blind faith in REMOTE_ADDR. Lighttpd uses PHP FastCGI & I find that X_FORWARDED_FOR + CLIENT_IP are both undefined anyway.

Comment: @DroidOS they are undefined because you're not using a proxy. If you want to restrict access by IP it's more appropriate to use ip-tables - but that's just the equivalent of testing REMOTE_ADDR which you _can_ trust to mean the machine that the request will respond to.