# How to get html out of youtube URL using php curl?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want to get the source code of Youtube URL (https) which is similar to what we see on - "View page source" option in browser.

Following is my php code - (index.php)

```
<?php
function gethtml($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $ip=rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,3)." (Windows NT ".rand(3,5).".".rand(0,2)."; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/".rand(3,5).".0.1");
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $url = $_REQUEST["url"];
    $html = gethtml($url);
    echo htmlspecialchars($html);
}
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form name="test" method="POST" action="./index.php"/>
            URL : <input type="text" name="url"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="See HTML" name="submit"/>
            <br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works for other URL'S but not for any youtube URL. Why ?

Comment: That CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER trick is pointless and won't "trick" them into believing your request comes from there...

Comment: But why ? It sends them a random IP as a message header, won't it ?

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] gives the IP address from which the request was sent to the web server. This is typically the visitor's address.
[See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262081/serverremote-addr-gives-server-ip-rather-than-visitor-ip)

Comment: Look into it a bit more @Mercury, try [anatomy of HTTP ..](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/).  What you are missing is that TCP provides the connection for HTTP, and I _think_ that the server will ignore whatever you put in the header and use the detail from the TCP connection.

Comment: so you are saying that the web server don't take into account the headers passed in packet having request for webpage and it takes it what TCP connection states ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not adamant on cURL you can just use:

```
file_get_contents();
```

That will return a url resource as a string, so:

```
echo file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyLGa0E3OXk');
```

That would print the source of the URL given.

Edit because of comment about header:

You can pass `file_get_contents` a context resource created with `stream_context_create()`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Is it possible to change the Header passed when accessing the file ? I want to change the IP Address in header like i did in above function using rand so as to prevent hitting the page multiple times and getting blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the changes. Got it now.

Comment: Still i am interested in knowing my mistake to learn apart from learning new things.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php
function getSSLPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

var_dump(getSSLPage($_POST["url"]));
?>
```

Comment: the var_dump outputs the following :- boolean false.

Comment: I've just tested that code with 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyLGa0E3OXk' and it works fine. What URL are you trying?

Comment: It returns the same result your your URL as well. I have hosted the same using WAMP Server, is there anything i need to set there for https pages ?